# Moving javascript into body

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am working in an ASP.NET MVC project that uses a lot of `@section scripts` blocks. We also use a lot of partial views. Currently, I have our global JS (**global.js**) rendered in the `<head>` element, which blocks the rest of the page from loading until it has finished loading. I want to move this JS into the body, but because my partial views are reliant on the global.js, this becomes a problem. The rendered HTML turns out to be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>

    <!-- Scripts/styles here -->
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Partial A -->
    <div id="PartialA">Partial A</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            Foo.bar();
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And `global.js`:

```
var Foo = {};
Foo.bar = function(){
    console.log("I did Foo.bar()!");
}
```

Is there anything I can do to place my global.js just before the `</body` tag while still allowing the JS that uses global.js to exist higher up in the body? Maybe some sort of custom "ready" event I can subscribe to?

Comment: Why not use `window.onload` and then create the script tag for the global.js ? Not sure if that would cause any problems depending on what dynamic data is coming from your js file. *Just an idea*

Answer (score 0):

why not in `Partial A`

```
window.initPartialA = function () {
 Foo.bar();
}
```

and in `Global`

```
if (window.initPartialA) {
  initPartialA();
}
```

This is really gross, I would figure out a way of how to organize your script tags in `asp` rather than doing this.